# sed command to insert multi line string after multi line search

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, command

I would like to insert lines of text into another text file after two specific lines.

Inserting after something similar to

```
some text...
  example text
    (
    );
some text...
```

I have a text file(containing two lines of text) that I would like sed to insert between the parentheses.

If the text file I am trying to insert contains something similar to the following

```
need this;
in between the parentheses;
```

Then I would like the result to look like this

```
some text...
  example text
    (
     need this;
     in between the parentheses;
    );
some text...
```

What ever the best solution would be can work(doesn't have to be sed).

EDIT for clarification

There are other open parentheses before the section where the text needs to be inserted e.g.

```
sometext...
sometext (sometext)....
sometext
  (
  );
  exampletext
    (
    );
sometext...
```

So, I would think that the "exampletext" would need to be reference to then look for the parentheses.  Also, it would would probably need to search for "exampletext" exactly since there are other lines within the document with "exampletextsometext..."

Once this has been completed the addition to the file would need to be saved over the original file.

Comment: Do you expect to have just one pair of parentheses in the file? Are they on a line by themselves? Are they at the start of the line? Are they the only thing on the line?

Comment: No, there are multiple instances of parentheses. Where they need to be inserted is at a point where they are by themselves as shown above. They are not actually at the beginning of the line(there are tabs or spaces that separate them from the beginning). They are the only character on the line. The unique thing about them is the example text, then (, then );

I have edited the original post to better show formatting of the spacing.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the open `(` is on a line by itself you could just do

```
sed -e '/^(/r fileToInsert' firstFile
```

since the `/^(/` finds the line where you want to insert ("a line starting with an open parenthesis"), and `r` means "read contents of file and insert at this point.

If the expression needed to determine the insertion point has to be more complex, please elaborate in comments. For example, "exactly an open parenthesis and nothing else" would be `/^($/`

**EDIT** thank you for clarifying the requirement. If you need to insert this text right after `example text` followed by an `(`, the following script ought to work. Put it in a file of its own, and make it executable (`chmod 755 myScript`), then run with `./myScript`.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '
/exampletext/ {
  N
  /(/ r multi2.txt
}' multi1.txt
```

Explanation:

```
/exampletext/ {     find a match of this text, then…
N                   go to the next line
/(/                 match open parenthesis
r multi2.txt        insert file 'multi2.txt' here
}'                  end of script
multi1.txt          name of input file
```

Note that this produces output to `stdout`. You could direct this to a new file name - for example

```
./myScript > newFile.txt
```

I tested this with the following input file (`multi1.txt`):

```
some text...
sometext...
sometext (sometext)....
  exampletext
  not the right string
    (
    );
sometext
  (
  );
  exampletext
    (
    );
sometext...
```

And it gave the output

```
some text...
sometext...
sometext (sometext)....
  exampletext
  not the right string
    (
    );
sometext
  (
  );
  exampletext
    (
insert this
and that
    );
sometext...
```

Which I think is what you wanted? The text is inserted where the `example text` is followed by an open parenthesis - but not when there's another line in between...

Comment: Sed would need to discern from other open parentheses in the document.
The unique quality of the section where the text needs to be inserted is
'example text
(
);'
where example text is unique with the parentheses following it.

Also, I am unsure if it matters, but there is spaces between the start of the line and the (. Like the following.

'     example text
              (
              );
'

Comment: @user3439830 - thanks for the clarification; see if the updated answer works for you?

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot. That's kind of how I figured it should look but wasn't structuring it correctly. I also just added the -i option after sed to update the file once completed.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of doing it with `awk`:

```
awk '/^\(/{print $0; while((getline line <"filetoInsert") > 0) print line; next}1' firstFile
```

**Explanation:**

- We use a simple regex `/^\(/` to state that look at the line that starts with an opening parenthesis.
- Once we encounter that line, we print it.
- We then use `getline` function to read through the second file.
- Once it has been read and printed completely, we use `next` to avoid default printing of the line of original file (our paren) again as we have turned on default printing using the `1` you see at the end.

Comment: I had been wondering how I would do this in `awk` (my second choice for "more complex" word processing after `sed`) - you answered it. I think that the `sed` solution is cleaner in this case, but I'm upvoting because you satisfied my curiosity (and confirmed my bias for `sed` in this case).

Comment: @Floris Thank you for the kind words. I completely agree, in some cases (such as this particular one) `sed` is alot cleaner, shorter and easier to understand and you had my upvote for it `:)`.

Comment: I have modified my original post to show the addition of the spaces before the (.  I have tried this method and it does not seem to yield the desired results. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @user3439830 You can modify the `regex` and say `/ *\(/` instead of what is given in the answer.

Comment: This addition inserted the file into the wrong section.  There are other parts of the document that have an open parentheses. The unique part about the section where the inserted text belongs is that it contains the `example text` then on the next line `(`. These two lines are also cascading as shown in the newly edited question above.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '$!N;/^(\n);$/{r insert_file' -e '};P;D' first_file
```

Answer (score 0):

also in python:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[2]) as secondFile:
    insertStrList=secondFile.readlines()

firstStrList=[]
with open(sys.argv[1]) as firstFile:
    while True:
        i_str=firstFile.readline()
        if not i_str: 
            break
        firstStrList.append(i_str)
        if i_str == '(\n':
            firstStrList+=insertStrList

print ''.join(firstStrList)
```

using it with `python mergeParenthesis.py a.txt b.txt`

But I agree Floris answer is easier ;)

cheers

Comment: "There isn't a single line Linux command that can't be turned into a dozen lines of Python." Seriously, I am a big fan of Python but I think it's overkill in this case. When I process simple text files, I reach for `sed` or `awk` (in that order). Python is for "real" problems, in my book... Have you tried to benchmark this? I wonder whether the line-by-line append operation might not become quite slow on larger files. Not sure how efficient Python is for that. Do you know?

Comment: Totally agree. I usually use awk, I'm not that expert in sed. But I have learned the 'r' flag yesterday with your answer. Thanks a lot.